# Active Diffeomorphism

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry

I am a little confused about active diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$. 
Let us focus on translation. When we say that we are doing an active translations does that means that all the particles $\gamma$,and fields $\psi$ including the metric $g$ are translated but the manifold itself gets untouched ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is a smooth, bijective correspondance between points of the manifold $M$ (think of it as a "permutation" of an uncountable set), and any geometric object $O_x$ located at $x\in M$ before the action of $f$ gets displaced to a geometric object $(f_\ast O_x)_{f(x)}$ located at $f(x)$, once again, in a smooth and bijective manner.

In this sense, the manifold itself "gets touched" too, because the map moves points around. It would help however, if OP clarified what they meant on the manifold "getting touched".

Comment: by touched i meant translated in this case